# jQuery wrapping text and elements between <hr> tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to wrap everything, including free text, that is between two `<hr>` elements.

Given this source:

```
<hr class=begin>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <a href=mauris.html>Mauris</a> id diam turpis, et faucibus nunc.
  <div><img src=foo.png /></div>
<hr class=end>
```

I need to wrap everything between the `hr.begin` and `hr.end` tags, like so:

```
<hr class=begin>
  <div class=content>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    <a href=mauris.html>Mauris</a> id diam turpis, et faucibus nunc.
    <div><img src=foo.png /></div>
  </div>
<hr class=end>
```

I cannot use a method like `.nextUntil('hr.end')` because this will not select the untagged text.

Comment: There are some very good answers posted. Patrick and J-P, I upvoted you both, but I can choose only one answer. And thanks to Evadne for the explanation of jQuery.dir - very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

I like this version better than my previous: http://jsfiddle.net/LbmCg/3/

*(Partly inspired from the answer **J-P** gave.)*

```
$('hr.begin').each(function(){
    var $set = $();
    var nxt = this.nextSibling;
    while(nxt) {
        if(!$(nxt).is('hr.end')) {
            $set.push(nxt);
            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
        } else break;
    } 
   $set.wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

---

**Original answer**

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LbmCg/

If there's more than one set to wrap, there will some adjustment needed.

```
var foundBegin = false;
var foundEnd = false;

$('hr.begin').parent()
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        if($(this).is('hr.begin')) {
            foundBegin = true;
        }
        if($(this).is('hr.end')) {
            foundEnd = true;
        }
        return foundBegin && !foundEnd;
    })

    .wrapAll('<div class="content"/>');​
```

jQuery's `.contents()` returns all nodes including text nodes. So here we traverse to the `.parent()` of the `hr.begin`, get all of its nodes using `.contents()` then filter through them, tracking when we've found the beginning and the end, and only returning the elements between them.

Then we use `.wrapAll()` to wrap them with the `div.content`.

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/
- http://api.jquery.com/filter/
- http://api.jquery.com/is/

---

**EDIT:** If there are multiple sets to wrap, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LbmCg/1/

**EDIT:** Cleaned things up a little in both examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
​$('hr.begin ~ hr.end').each(function(){

    var contents = [], node, begin = $(this).prevAll('hr.begin')[0];

    if (node = this.previousSibling) do {
        if (node === begin) break;
        contents.unshift(node);
    } while (node = node.previousSibling);

    $(contents).wrapAll('<div class="content">');

});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This can handle multiple sets of the `begin - contents - end` sequence. It will look for all `hr.end` elements preceded by `hr.begin` elements and will, for each `hr.end`, find the preceding nodes between it and `hr.begin`, and then it'll wrap them all in a `<div class=content>`.

Comment: I tried it and the contents comes out with the element order reversed.

Answer (score 1):

`theElement.contents()` will recognize **text nodes**.  Since `jQuery.nextUntil()` is actually a wrapper around `jQuery.dir`, which does

```
dir: function( elem, dir, until ) {

    var matched = [], cur = elem[dir];
    while ( cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery( cur ).is( until )) ) {
        if ( cur.nodeType === 1 ) {
            matched.push( cur );
        }
        cur = cur[dir];
    }
    return matched;
},
```

where text nodes that get filtered out have a `nodeType` of 3, a custom `jQuery.dir` might help here.

—

I tried this solution with Patrick’s test data and it works:

```
jQuery.dirIncludingTextNodes = function( elem, dir, until ) {
    var matched = [], cur = elem[dir];
    while ( cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery( cur ).is( until )) ) {
        if ( cur.nodeType === 1 ||cur.nodeType === 3 ) {
            matched.push( cur );
        }
        cur = cur[dir];
    }
    return matched;
};

jQuery.nextUntilIncludingTextNodes = function( elem, i, until ) {

    return jQuery.dirIncludingTextNodes( elem, "nextSibling", until );

};

$('hr.begin').nextUntilIncludingTextNodes("hr").wrap($("<div>").addClass("content"));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, but I was using a CMS based on FCKEditor that didn't work so hot because of insertion of newline TextNodes from using the nextSibling property. I generally don't like to mix jQuery stuff with native JavaScript if I can help it either. I came up with this snippet that updates Patrick DW's solution that would probably be a bit more friendly for jQuery usage. Also doesn't require classes to determine next block.

```
$('hr').each(function(){
    var $set = $([]);
    var $nxt = $(this).next();
    while($nxt.length) {
        if(!$($nxt).is('hr')) {
            $set = $set.add($nxt);
            $nxt=$nxt.next();
        } else break;
    } 
    $set.wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you HR and other tags are inside a div e.g.

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <hr class=begin>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <a href=mauris.html>Mauris</a> id diam turpis, et faucibus nunc.
  <div><img src=foo.png /></div>
  <hr class=end>
</div>
```

You can use [jQuery.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) e.g.

```
 $("#mydiv").contents().each(function(i,el){
  console.log(i,el)
  })
```

outputs:

```
0, [object Text]
1, [object HTMLHRElement]
2, [object Text]
3, http://jsbin.com/mauris.html
4, [object Text]
5, [object HTMLDivElement]
6, [object Text]
7, [object HTMLHRElement]
8, [object Text]
```

So you can easily club them in groups as you need.

​

Answer (score 0):

A extended version of user191688's code.
This on is not only looking for the "until" in siblings but also up and down the tree.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({
        nextUntilExtended: function(until) {
            var $set = $();
            var nxt = this.get(0).nextSibling;
            while(nxt) {
                if(!$(nxt).is(until)) {
                    if(nxt.nodeType != 3 && $(nxt).has(until)){
                        nxt = nxt.firstChild;
                    }else{
                        $set.push(nxt);
                        if(nxt.nextSibling){
                            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
                        }else{
                            nxt = nxt.parentNode.nextSibling;
                        }
                    }
                } else break;
            }
            return($set);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```